# Disable IPv6 via WIFI to Pixel 3a

Tags: wi-fi, google-pixel, ipv6, google-pixel-3

I have Pixel 3a without SIM card, so I use this phone only with WIFI.

How can I disable IPV6 in this phone? That the phone will use only IPv4?

Comment: So what is the problem caused by IPv6?

Comment: I have script that debug only IPv4